# Colour map in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt. I am trying to make a simple map like in the picture bellow, and color each slot a different color based on some value calculated by my program. Then when I tick a checkbox, the value will be displayed on the slot on top of the color. So how can I do this? Any pointing is greatly appreciated.

[image: map]

Comment: You may refer to [**`QColorDialog`**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcolordialog.html)

Comment: You can also take a look at the color map of QCustomPlot : http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/demos/colormapdemo

Answer (score 0):

The trick to drawing such figures is to realize that it's possible to draw a single pixel multiple times.

Each slot is a rectangle, drawn in either white or a color.

On top of those rectangles, you draw the following things:

1. A grid of black lines
2. A black circle (not filled)
3. A number of white circles, around the black circle.

The last step erases colored pixels outside the circle from step 2.